# How does javascript resolve parameters?

Tags: javascript

I am fairly new to `JavaScript` and coming from a different programming background I have a tough time to understand how `JavaScript` knows how to resolve parameters passed to a function.

Let's look at and easy example. from the [documentation of jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/on/) `.on`, I see 2 different signatures:

> .on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )
>
> .on( events [, selector ] [, data ] )

However, the following snippet produces perfectly valid code and does what is intended:

```js
$(function() {
  let dat = {a: 1, b: 2}
  $('#do').on('click', dat, function(evt) {
    alert(evt.data.b);
  });
  $('#do2').on('click', function(evt) {
    alert("click");
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="do">
  Click!
</button>
<button id="do2">
  Click!
</button>
```

How does `JavaScript` "know" that `dat`in the first case is the data (and not the `selector`)? Apparently there is no positional matching of neither of the two signatures? So how does that work internally and how could I use this pattern for my own functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How doe JavaScript "know" that datin the first case is the data (and not the selector)?

It doesn't. The language just passes the arguments given by the caller to the function. Figuring out what the caller passed is handled by the function, not the language.

> Apparently there is no positional matching of neither of the two signatures?

JavaScript *only* uses positional matching. As of ES2015+, it will also provide defaults for missing parameters (or parameters whose passed argument is the value `undefined`).

> So how does that work internally and how could I use this pattern for my own functions?

In JavaScript, you don't have to pass the same number of arguments to a function as the number of parameters it declares; you can pass fewer or more. The function can tell what you've passed it in three ways:

- By looking at the special `arguments` array-like object which is created for each function and contains the arguments and a `length` property saying how many there are.
- By looking at the values of the parameters and/or their types. If the caller hasn't provided an argument for a parameter, the parameter's value will be the value `undefined`.
- In ES2015+, by using a *rest parameter* which gathers up all the provided arguments at that position and afterward into a true array.

Here's an example:

```js
function example(obj, number, str) {
    console.log("Arguments received: " + arguments.length);
    if (typeof number === "string") {
        // Caller provided a string, not anumber, as the second
        // argument; move things around
        str = number;
        number = undefined;
    }
    console.log("obj", obj);
    console.log("number", number);
    console.log("str", str);
}
console.log('Calling example({}, 42, "forty-two");');
example({}, 42, "forty-two");
console.log('Calling example({}, "no number given");');
example({}, "no number given");
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;£
}
```

Here's an example of using a rest parameter:

```js
function example(obj, ...rest) {
    let number, str;
    if (rest.length === 2) {
        [number, str] = rest; // This is called "destructuring assignment"
    } else {
        [str] = rest;
    }
    if (typeof number === "string") {
        // Caller provided a string, not anumber, as the second
        // argument; move things around
        str = number;
        number = undefined;
    }
    console.log("obj", obj);
    console.log("number", number);
    console.log("str", str);
}
console.log('Calling example({}, 42, "forty-two");');
example({}, 42, "forty-two");
console.log('Calling example({}, "no number given");');
example({}, "no number given");
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;£
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Looking at the [jQuery source code for `on`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/cf84696fd1d7fe314a11492606529b5a658ee9e3/src/event.js#L41), types are checked by hand and any omitted parameters are accounted for manually (parameters always populate left-to-right):

```
function on( elem, types, selector, data, fn, one ) {
    var origFn, type;

    // Types can be a map of types/handlers
    if ( typeof types === "object" ) {

        // ( types-Object, selector, data )
        if ( typeof selector !== "string" ) {

            // ( types-Object, data )
            data = data || selector;
            selector = undefined;
        }
        for ( type in types ) {
            on( elem, type, selector, data, types[ type ], one );
        }
        return elem;
    }

    if ( data == null && fn == null ) {

        // ( types, fn )
        fn = selector;
        data = selector = undefined;
    } else if ( fn == null ) {
        if ( typeof selector === "string" ) {
```

...etc.

This might be shocking coming from a non-dynamically typed background, but it's pretty commonplace in JS.

Comment: I also needed to check the source code on this to realize this feature of jQuery is just a bunch of if statements combined with typeof.

Comment: Yeah, it's sort of like the fluent syntax you can see in JS like `expect(foo).not.toBe(bar)`. At first, it's totally amazing that it works, then after looking into it, it turns out not to be magic at all, then looking further it actually seems less clear for the client of the library and I wonder why they went through all the trouble.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the jQuery source code. Actually, I was on the git repo as my first step, but I could not find the source file where `on`  was defined (searching for `on`, well, it gives you a lot of hits ;). +1

Comment: It becomes clearer and clearer now. So, if I want to pass a string to the `data` argument I have to run `let dat = "s"; $('#do').on('click', null, dat, function() {})` because `$('#do').on('click', dat, function() {})` does not work for apparent reasons.I also could pass `undefined` but `.on('click',,dat)` does not work. What is the preferred way `undefined` or `null`?

Comment: It doesn't matter as far as jQ is concerned because `undefined == null` thanks to type coercion. I'm not sure what best practices would dictate, but the docs say "If the selector is **null** or omitted" (emphasis mine), so this seems reasonable.

Answer (score 4):

> How does `JavaScript` "know" that `dat` in the first case is the data (and
>   not the `selector`)?

It doesn't.

In fact functions in javascript do not need to declare their parameters explicitly. Each function has access to an object called [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) which holds (as you may have guessed) all the arguments passed to the function. So the function can just look at this object to find out all the parameters passed to it.

```js
function foo() {
    console.log(arguments);
}

foo(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

> So how does that work internally and how could I use this pattern for
>   my own functions?

I believe I already explained how it works, but my advice is *Don't use this pattern for your own functions*. If you can, I'd even advice not to write plain javascript. There are many supersets of the language available which allows you to be more explicit with the types and parameters accepted by your function. [`Typescript`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) is one such language that introduces the much needed type safety when writing javascript. You can also try [`scala.js`](https://www.scala-js.org/) if you are into that sort of thing.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out to supersets. Actually, I am not planning yet to do any serious programming myself in `JavaScript`. I need however to ahve a working understanding of it for my `shiny` applications. +1

Answer (score 2):

`selector` has to be a string. `dat` has to be an object. `handler` has to be a function. There is nothing in JavaScript that can do this for you: all of these checks are done explicitly in jQuery code.

Comment: "There is nothing in JavaScript that can do this for you": aren't there functions in JavaScript that have optional parameters that JS has to  type check to determine what they are?

Comment: @symlink There is no type checking in JavaScript, and all parameters are optional.

Comment: @symlink JS has no typechecking. You may want to try typescript

Comment: @Amadan not trying to argue, but take `addEventListener`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener. Third parameter can be either `options` object or `useCapture` boolean.

Comment: @symlink What I mean is types have to be checked manually, using `typeof` operator or through duck typing; there is no type checking like in Java where the correct signature can be selected from several possibilities automatically, based on the signature. (And also, `addEventListener` is not actually implemented in JavaScript.)